# Defined patern for mysql table primary key

Tags: sql, mysql

is there anyway to create lets say pattern for primary key i.e. for table products such pattern would by p-1,p-2... p-n etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can manually create and enforce that pattern into your application (or using triggers). A primary key just needs to be unique to work.

But I don't recommend it. In your sample, seems `P-1` have a business meaning. And, if it belongs to your business realm, it can be changed. While most database have a `UPDATE CASCADE` equivalent, it doesn't change basic reason you shouldn't use that as key: it's *information*, not *data*.

I suggest you to create a field named `ProductCode char(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE` and maybe to fill it with `P-00000001`, `P-00000002`, and so on. Maybe you do prefer to use a `varchar`: this doesn't matter, as it must fulfill your business requirement. Create an `Id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` field to use as primary key, as it doesn't never needs to be changed.

Comment: "int IDENTITY" on MySQL will be "INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY"